# C# SendKeys.Send doesn't work in games

Tags: c#, input, macros, bots, sendkeys

[Project GitHub Link](https://github.com/gkaragoz/Knight-Online-Macro)

I created a Macro software that program follows your keyboard inputs in time intervals. I gave project link in above. As you can see there is an issue on GitHub page. If I need to explain in here detailed, so in the program I have an command line like:

```
SendKeys.Send("2");
```

This works in any kind of program. But when I try in any game. That doesn't work. Actually it works but weirdly. In game, when I hit enter to open text input area, it works. But otherwise doesn't work. How can I fix that?

There is also how software looks like.

[image: There is also how software looks like.]

By the way you need to open exe in Administrator mode. It works in any user mode on notepad, notepad++ or google chrome or even in visual studio. But if you want to test in any kind of game, you need to open exe in Administrator mode.

Comment: Try it with SendInput. SendKeys is apparently blocked by some programs.

Also, what is '2' supposed to do in game?

Comment: SendKeys sends the key strokes to the currently focused window. Sounds like in the game, you need to send an enter key ("\n") to the main game window first and then wait until the text input area is focused and then send "2".

Comment: @wbt11a I'll try to use SendInput. Do you have any example or well documanted infos for this? Also, in game if you press any number of key like 1-2-3-4 so on when you don't type that makes character uses skills or potions. It affects skill-bar.

Comment: @o_weisman I don't want to type anything. That was just checking for is it working or not. It works when I type. But I want to use skill in game which is only happens when you press number key while you're not focusing text input area.